# JavaScript equivalent of the MySQL function SUBSTRING_INDEX()

Tags: javascript, mysql, string

[**SUBSTRING_INDEX()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) in MySQL returns a substring from a string before the specified number of occurrences of the delimiter.

Is there any equivalent function in JavaScript? I need to perform the same thing.. but on a string value in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.stackoverflow.com', '.', 1) result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| www    |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.stackoverflow.com', '.', 2) result;
+-------------------+
| result            |
+-------------------+
| www.stackoverflow |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

JavaScript:

```
function substringIndex (input, delimiter, index) {
  var arr = input.split(delimiter);
  arr.splice(index, arr.length - index);
  return arr.join(delimiter);
}

console.log(substringIndex('www.stackoverflow.com', '.', 1)); 
// www

console.log(substringIndex('www.stackoverflow.com', '.', 2)); 
// www.stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 0):

**indexOf** may be what you are after: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp

Of course, you'd have to combine this with something like **substr**: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

**EDIT:**
The more I looked into this, the more difficult it got to give something exactly like what you are looking for. One way to do this is with a [Regular Expression](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml), or, I wrote a simple little function that will let you use syntax nearly identical to **SUBSTRING_INDEX()**

```
function substringIndex(str, char, occurrence){
    var newStr = '';
    var occurrenceMatches = 0;

    for (var i=0; str.length; i++){
        if (str.charAt(i)==char) occurrenceMatches++;
        if (occurrenceMatches==occurrence) break;
        newStr += str.charAt(i);
    }

    return newStr;
}
alert(substringIndex('www.mysql.com', '.', 2));
```

Comment: What about my split, splice, join method? It looks equivalent to the MySQL function, and a bit more terse than the for loop method you suggest.

Comment: Agreed. Your example is more pretty.

Answer (score 0):

An old question I know, but just for the record and in case it helps anyone, the following is a slight updated to the selected answer which allows substring_index to work exactly as it does in MySQL i.e. also allowing for negative indexes.

```
function substring_index( input, delimiter, index ) {
    var arr = input.split( delimiter );
    if( index < 0 ){
       index = arr.length + index;
       arr.splice( 0, index );
    }else{
       arr.splice( index, arr.length - index );
    }
       return arr.join( delimiter );
 }
```