# extract first and last name from pattern email address

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am trying to get the First Name and Last Name out of a series of email addresses. There is a pattern for each e-mail address. The pattern is first.last@company.com but in some cases, it can be something like first.middle.last@company.com. The main point being that there can be something in between the first and last name in the e-mail but not always. 
The main pattern, which is always the same, is that the first string, until the first dot is always the first name, and the last name is always the last character series until the @ char which begins from the previous DOT.
Examples:

charles.bukowski@company.com
first: charles
last:bukowski

charles.mark.bukowski@copmany.com
first: charles
last:bukowski

charles.x.markus.bukowski@company.com
first: charles
last:bukowski

Getting the first name is easy. I have the following variables:

```
var empmail = 'charles.x.markus.bukowski@company.com'
var empname = empmail.substring(0, empmail.indexOf("."));
```

I cannot find the way to get out the last name.

Comment: MySQL has a useful function called SUBSTRING_INDEX() that would solve your problem select SUBSTRING_INDEX("a.b.c.d",".",-1) returns "d" Here is a javascript version of that [Previous StackOverFlow solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839944/javascript-equivalent-of-the-mysql-function-substring-index)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting usernames and userid from E-mail IDs using Ms-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798098/extracting-usernames-and-userid-from-e-mail-ids-using-ms-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method:

```
var empmail = 'charles.x.markus.bukowski@company.com'

var fullName = empmail.split('@')[0].split('.');

var firstName = fullName[0];
var lastName = fullName[ fullName.length-1 ]
```

Comment: This is wonderful! It's a split in a split. I haven't thought about this. Could you please tell me, what exactly does the [0]?

Comment: Split returns an array of strings. This expression `[0]` returns the first element of the array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: var firstName = fullName[0];
var lastName = fullName[-1]

Answer (score 4):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with regex to get the name.

```js
var empmail = 'charles.x.markus.bukowski@company.com'

var match = empmail.match(/^(\w+)\..*\.(\w+)@/);

var empname = match[1];
var emplname = match[2];

console.log(
  empname,
  emplname
)
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/fgQlZx/1)

---

Or using [`String#lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastindexof) method

```js
var empmail = 'charles.x.markus.bukowski@company.com'
var empname = empmail.substring(0, empmail.indexOf(".")); // get first name

// get complete name part
var namePart = empmail.substring(0, empmail.indexOf("@"));
// get last name from name part
var emplname = namePart.substring(namePart.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

console.log(
  empname,
  emplname
)
```

---

Or using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) methods.

```js
var empmail = 'charles.x.markus.bukowski@company.com'
// split by `.` and get first element
var empname = empmail.split('.')[0];

// split name part and get last element from array
var emplname = empmail.split('@')[0].split('.').pop();

console.log(
  empname,
  emplname
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can also use this approach for the given email ids**

```
var emailfirstname = a.slice(0,a.indexOf('@')).split('.')[0]

var emailLastname = a.slice(0,a.indexOf('@')).split('.')[a.slice(0,a.indexOf('@')).split('.').length - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get your last name:

javascript:

```
empmail.match(/[a-z]+(?=@)/i);
```

php:

```
preg_match("/[a-z]+(?=@)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```